KServe endpoint ui showing revision failed in kubeflow
I have installed kubeflow on my kubernetes cluster. On creating pipeline my model is created but kserve endpoint pod is showing revision failed Error.
*status:
conditions:

lastTransitionTime: "2024-11-30T09:57:07Z"
message: 'Revision "App_name"
failed with message: Initial scale was never achieved.'
reason: RevisionFailed
status: "False"
type: ConfigurationsReady
lastTransitionTime: "2024-11-30T09:46:36Z"
message: Configuration "App_name"
does not have any ready Revision.
reason: RevisionMissing
status: "False"
type: Ready
lastTransitionTime: "2024-11-30T09:46:36Z"
message: Configuration "App_name"
does not have any ready Revision.
reason: RevisionMissing
status: "False"
type: RoutesReady*

I dont have internet connection on my machine. I followed same steps as i followed on machine with internet connection and endpoint is working fine there.
